# set description not working

Tags: android

```
TextView Txt1 = new TextView(this);
Txt1.setText("describe");
Txt1.setClickable(true);
Txt1.setContentDescription("this is description of text");
Txt1.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 16);
Txt1.setTextColor(Color.rgb(187, 88, 15));
Txt1.setPadding(10, 10, 0, 0);
Txt1.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF,Typeface.BOLD);
```

I try to setContentDescription for text view but it will not shows description if i place the cursor above text. how to do it

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentations](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setContentDescription%28java.lang.CharSequence%29), **setContentDescription()** allows you to associate a textual description to the view. The docs state that it's primarily used to support accessibility, ***so I assume it's there to support screen readers.***

**This is especially true for views that do not have textual representation (For example, ImageButton).**